# Problems submitting ajax form to PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, serialization

I am sending off form data using jquery serialize as follows:

```
$.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            datatype : 'html',
            data: $('#form').serialize();,
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status === "success") {
                    $('.result').text("Success!!");
                } else if (response.status === "error") {
                    $('.result').text("Error!!");
                }
            }
        });
```

This is passed into the PHP script successfully but i am getting the following error in my PHP.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$name' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\Users\Jberke\Documents\Projects\theRetros\src\process.php on line 10
```

My PHP script is as follows:

```
<?php
$autoResponse = true; //if set to true auto response email will be sent, if you don't want autoresponse set it to false
$autoResponseSubject = "Demo Contact Form"; 
$autoResponseMessage = "Hi, thank you testing the JQuery Contact Form Demo.";
$autoResponseHeaders = "From: email_from@yourWebsite.com";  

//we need to get our variables first
$email_to =   'jamie_b25@hotmail.com';
$subject  =   'A enquiry for The Retros!'
$name     =   $_POST['name'];
$email    =   $_POST['email'];
$message  =   $_POST['message'];

$body = "From: $name \r\nMessage: \r\n$message";

/*the $header variable is for the additional headers in the mail function,
 we are asigning 2 values, first one is FROM and the second one is REPLY-TO.
 That way when we want to reply the email gmail(or yahoo or hotmail...) will know
 who are we replying to. */
$headers  = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: test@test.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";


if(mail($email_to, $subject, $body, $headers)){
    if($autoResponse === true){
        mail($email, $autoResponseSubject, $autoResponseMessage, $autoResponseHeaders);
    }
    echo 'success'; // we are sending this text to the ajax request telling it that the mail is sent..
}else{
    echo 'error';// ... or this one to tell it that it wasn't sent
}
```

?>

Im not sure what is happening here but it seems the serialised data isn't being accessed properly. Here is a snippet of a console log of my serialised data.

```
name=Jamie+Berke&email=jamie_b25%40hotmail.com&message=testing+123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a semi-colon in the PHP script on the line above the one that gives the error.

```
$subject  =   'A enquiry for The Retros!'  // <--- Here a ; should be added.
$name     =   $_POST['name'];
$email    =   $_POST['email'];
```

Often, when you get a syntax error like this, it is actually in the line above (or sometimes even higher). The PHP parser thinks the previous statement isn't finished (because of the missing semi-colon), and continues parsing the same statement. At that point it gets confused by the unexpected begin of the next statement. So, when you get a message like this for line 10, make sure to look on line 9 or 8 too.

Comment: thank you for this! Although my script still isn't submitting the form or returning the success or fail data. I am getting no PHP errors this time though so something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you forgot a semikolon here:

```
$subject  =   'A enquiry for The Retros!'
```

Should be:

```
$subject  =   'A enquiry for The Retros!';
```